# Tamper packets with OVS switch

Tags: security, network-programming, sdn, openflow, openvswitch

I want to implement a malicious (programmable) OVS switch in a SDN network that can calculate the hash of the packet and tamper data (the PACKET_OUT precisely) before forwarding it to the next hop.
I'm new to Open vSwitch and I searched for tutorials and didn't find anything helpful regarding this task.

Can please show me how to do it?

Comment: OVS could be auxiliary tool for you but it is irrelevant for your purpose. Best way to tamper with data would be to make transparent proxy so you would inspect data in user land without need for recalculation of check sums. At application level you have much more freedom for tampering. So you need to use iptables to modify destination of frames to be able to capture them. At user-land you can query iptables where frames were going before they got "re-routed" and implement second hop connection in such mitm setup/app. Take a look at [sslsplit](https://www.roe.ch/SSLsplit) as an example.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Maxim.
But I need to inject data and perform calculations from PACKET_OUT packet at the switch level in a SDN topology.
Can it be done with OVS switches or other switches compatible with Mininet?